# Angular routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing

recently I've done angular tutorial at angular getting started. Then I tried to do a little example by myself, but the routing doesn't seem to work. When I start the page the only thing I see is white.Just to mention the path I'm looking is `http://localhost:8000/app/index.html#/title`. My app looks like this:

---

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="test">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">

  <script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>

  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-view></div>
</body>

</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var test = angular.module( 'test', [ 'ngRoute', 'testControllers' ] );

test.config( ['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
          when('/title', {
            templateUrl: 'title.html',
            controller: 'TitleCtrl'
          }).
          otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/title'
          });
    }
]);
```

**controllers.js**

```
var testControllers = angular.module( 'testControllers', [] );

testControllers.controller( 'TitleCtrl', [ '$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.select_system = [
        "MOAB",
        "Amoeba",
        "Component Library",
        "SLURM",
        "UniCloud",
        "UniCluster",
        "UNICORE",
        "ProActive"
      ];
    }
]);
```

**templates/title.html**

```
<select ng-repeat="system in select_system">
  <option>{{system}}</option>
</select>
```

My path looks like this:
TextExample
 - app
 - app/bower_components
 - app/js/app.js
 - app/js/controllers.js
 - templates/title.html

---

```
bower.json
{
  "name": "TestExample",
  "description": "TestProject",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "authors": [
    "Vyivrain <sashaverhun@rambler.ru>"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.3.x",
    "angular-mocks": "1.3.x",
    "jquery": "1.10.2",
    "bootstrap": "~3.1.1",
    "angular-route": "1.3.x",
    "angular-resource": "1.3.x",
    "angular-animate": "1.3.x"
  }
}
```

**.bowerrc**

```
{
  "directory": "app/bower_components",
  "interactive": false
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "TestExample",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "TestProject",
  "main": "index.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "bower install",
    "prestart": "npm install",
    "start": "http-server -a 0.0.0.0 -p 8000",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "preupdate-webdriver": "npm install"
  },
  "author": "Vyivrain",
  "license": "BSD-2-Clause",
  "dependencies": {
    "bower": "~1.3.12",
    "http-server": "~0.6.1",
    "karma": "~0.12.24",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.1.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.1.5",
    "protractor": "~1.0.0",
    "shelljs": "~0.2.6",
    "tmp": "~0.0.23"
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems you forget load you own js file in your html.

Comment: I added my own js files now, a dumb problem, thx.But it still doesn't work.But now in console it gives a problem `Failed to load template: title.html`.

Comment: route configuration for title suggest that your index.html and title.html is in same folder. I suspect this is not the case. Please provide templateUrl w.r.t index.html file. Also you may wish to use browser debugger to see if angular tries to load appropriate template.

Comment: Got it working changing url with `templatesUrl:"templates/title.html"`

Comment: Thx all for your time!

Comment: Good job including lots of detail in your question. Btw, don't hesitate to put the working fix into an answer below and accept it. It gives everyone warm fuzzy feelings!

Answer (score 4):

app.js must look like this:

```
            var test = angular.module( 'test', [ 'ngRoute', 'testControllers' ] );

            test.config( ['$routeProvider',
                function($routeProvider) {
                  $routeProvider.
                      when('/title', {
                        templateUrl: 'templates/title.html',
                        controller: 'TitleCtrl'
                      }).
                      otherwise({
                        redirectTo: '/title'
                      });
                }
            ]);
```

Comment: I wish there were more explanations associated with answers as to the why. The reason for this is because the app.js should be at the root of your website/app, requiring the proper path to the view html. Please consider upgrading to component routing in 1.5 and get ready for Angular 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that in your route.js you missed to write templateUrl : 'templates/title.html'. Instead you have written templateUrl : 'title.html'.

Other solution could -

In your index.html write this in bottom:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="title.html">
 <select ng-repeat="system in select_system">
  <option>{{system}}</option>
 </select>
</script>
```

In this way you don't have to make a new file called title.html. Very useful if your template is small and frequently used.Also as there is no ajax call to get the template so it is rendered faster.

But more than this, always look your console in browser. In case of any error, angular js provides very good logs to detect it. As in your case you must be receiving an error.

Comment: He answered his question in the comments below his question with this answer. this was a nice and correct assumption

Answer (score 0):

### **Check chrome dev tools network tab you may see**

> cannot send xhr in data:// or file:// mode only available in https://
>   http://  mode

now the solution either make your browser to serve xhr in all modes or make a node server or anyother that you like

Answer (score 0):

If you can upgrade; please upgrade to Angular 1.5 and use the New-Router which makes good use of components. By doing this you will be more prepared for Angular 2.0 upgrade when its released.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for not showing your title.html is because it is not getting the right path of title.html file , maybe you have put title.html in some folder, usually we put all application view in templates folder or views folder , so you have change the route according.
For example if you put your views in views folder so you have to change route templateUrl in app.js like this.

```
var test = angular.module( 'test', [ 'ngRoute', 'testControllers' ] );

test.config( ['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
       when('/title', {
         templateUrl: 'views/title.html',
         controller: 'TitleCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/title'
      });
  }
]);
```